# How to make a dynamic progressbar with data received from an api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an api which sents score if someone does the math, chemistry or physics correct. The api is sends a response like this

```
{
  "scores": {
    "maths": 28,
    "chemistry": 9,
    "physics": 26,
  }
}
```

So if a person has done a problem then it'd post the answer and we get the score from the api. now I want is to have the scores show in kind of a progressbar.
This is how I have coded my textarea and their functions and progressbar

```
export default class Science extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      snippetDescription: "",
      scoredata: [],
    };
  }
render{
 return(
  <>
    <textarea
              class="textareaclass"
              placeholder="Enter your text here"
              onChange={snippetDescription =>
                this.setState({ snippetDescription })
              }
            ></textarea>
    <Button
               className="btn savebtn"
               onClick={() => this.scoreanalysis({ ...this.state })}
               >
               Analyse
    </Button>
  </>
)}
```

this is the function where we will fetch the api and store the score for progressbar

```
  scoreanalysis = snippetDescription => {
    fetch("/api/marksapi/:", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        snippetdesc: "snippetDescription"
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(textdata => {
            this.setState({
            scoredata: textdata.scores,  //Is this how I save the scores in scoredata to later use in the progressbar?
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  };
```

The problem is I have not done much work in api so how do I store the values of maths, chemistry and physics in the scoredata state variable and access it to make the progressbar dynamic.

This is the progressbar I have made so far, not working obviously because I believe, fetching from the api wasn't correct so can anyone please show me where it's wrong and correct me.

```
    <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"
                          progressbar current="{scoredata.math}">
                          {scoredata.math}
                          <span class="sr-only">10% Complete</span>
              </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this for a loading bar for an upload progress. I'm using bootstrap so [I used their progress bar element](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/progress/):

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

But as you mentioned, you wanted this to be dynamic. So what you want is for when the progress bar component loads, you want it to make the API call and pass a callback function to modify the state to that value which you can plug into the progress bar.

So using my Bootstrap example, the progress bar might now look like this:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style={{width: uploadProgress + "%"}} aria-valuenow={uploadProgress} aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

So when you load in this component, run a function (when the component mounts) that makes your API call, but pass in a callback function to update `uploadProgress`.

I'm using React Hooks (I'd highly recommend them) and here's how I set up `uploadProgress`:

```
const uploadProgress = useSelector(state => state.uploadProgress);
```

so I'm making a call to the state. This state is updated by the API function.

So to summarise:

1. Make your API results run a function (send an action to an actionCreator) to update the state.
2. Access this state in your progress bar component
3. Use that state value as the value for your progress bar(s)

Let me know if you've got any questions - I am new to this myself but that's how I manged to do it and it works pretty well!

Comment: I've never use hooks, I'm comfortable with class components because I've been developing in class components since I started. Also my code is just a small part of a big component so it'd be a problem to change everything to hooks now. Can you show it in class component. Also, you didn't mention about the scoredata in api call, was it right to set state that way

Comment: Ok, if you're using a class component then you will want to use the [connect()](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) function to [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) and use that to access the progress bar value through the class component props (e.g. this.props.progressValue)

edit: and yes, using setState with those scores is the correct way to do it (I think, I'm still new to this too)

Comment: so I will have to use redux for the states. It can't be done with just react like the one I did in the scoreanalysis function???

Comment: I'm not sure - I've spent the last few months using React + Redux heavily so It's all I really know, I'm trying to remember how this would be done without Redux but I'm not too sure. Redux is great for this kind of stuff as it makes handling the Store and State a lot easier between different components - hence why I've been using it so much.